# Yarn: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443

Tags: github, npm, yarnpkg, elm

When I install ELM via yarn, I get

> -- ERROR -----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> Something went wrong while fetching the following URL:
>
> https://github.com/elm/compiler/releases/download/0.19.1/binary-for-windows-64-bit.gz
>
> It is saying:
>
> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
>
> NOTE: You can avoid npm entirely by downloading directly from:
>   https://github.com/elm/compiler/releases/download/0.19.1/binary-for-windows-64-bit.gz

When I manually browse to https://github.com/elm/compiler/releases/download/0.19.1/binary-for-windows-64-bit.gz. I get

[image]

However other people can access the link and it downloads the file.

**EDIT:**

HOSTS File:

> 127.0.0.1 view-localhost # view localhost server
>
> 127.0.0.1       mydevsnapcap.com www.mydevsnapcap.com app.mydevsnapcap.com internal.mydevsnapcap.com
>
> 0.0.0.1   mssplus.mcafee.com

**Edit**
This use to work a few days ago.

More tests:
I cannot access it from my phone and pc using my fibre connection, but I can access it on both my phone and mobile using my mobile connection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that it was my ISP that was for some reason blocking the link. I switch to using the google dns and all is good in the hood: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using

Comment: Maybe mark this as the correct answer then so it doesn't show up as unanswered. :)

Answer (score 4):

Something in your computer or on your network is resolving the domain github.com to 127.0.0.1, i.e. localhost. Hence, everytime you attempt this access, it tries to reach a service running on the very same computer you're making the request from.

Check your DNS settings.

Check that there are no entries for `github.com` in the *hosts* file (on Windows `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, everywhere else `/etc/hosts`).

If you're running something like [Pi-Hole](https://pi-hole.net/) on your network, check, that it doesn't catch github.com

Comment: Where can I find more info on how those entries being added in this file, because I have a lot of websites in there, lol

Comment: @DavydVeremchuk: There's no "standard" method of adding entries to that file other than that *any* program could have done it. It might also happen by *Group Policies* (GPO; if you're connected to an Active Directory domain). Also it's often used for blocking advertisements and trackers. But it's also used by malware to redirect traffic into a man-in-the-middle attack. I'd be very alert about any changes to that file not initiated by GPO or yourself. If those changes are due to something you didn't initiate, I recommend being alert and maybe consider the system to be compromised.

Comment: I've a lot of redirects from websites with russian antivirus software in this file. From what you said I suppose it was added by some malware.